# Reference a specific list item through a controller

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I currently have a list that is coming through a store fine, and the itemTpl is putting a div inside each list item with a specific ID. What I want to do know is use a controller to execute different functions on each specific list item when it is tapped. I have a controller set up but it doesn't seem to be referencing it.

Any help would be great

View:

```
Ext.define('tourApp.view.TourInfo', {

extend: 'Ext.List',
xtype: 'TourInfo',
config: {
    navigationBar: {
            hidden: true
        },

        title: 'Tour Info',
        iconCls: 'MyTourInfoIcon nav-schedule',
        items: [
            {
                docked: 'top',
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                title: '<span class="logo"></span>'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'list',
                store: 'TourInfoList',
                id: 'lolol',
                itemTpl: '<div id="TIList{id}" class="TIList"><div class="TIListTitle">{title}</div></div>'
            }
        ]


}

});
```

Controller:

```
Ext.define('tourApp.controller.TourInfo', {

extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

config: {
    refs: {
        Tdetails: 'TourInfo',
        main: 'TourInfo'
    },
    control: {
        "TourInfo list #TIList1": {
            tap: 'test'
        }
    }
},

test: function() {
    console.log('Success');

}

});
```

Comment: use [itemTap](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.DataView-event-itemtap) event to do whatever you want to do with that item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`select`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List-event-select) event for this..

```
control: {
    'TourInfo list': {
        select: function(list, record, eOpts) { console.log('test'); }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is still not logging anything to the console.